# meaning of II symbol in a math equation

Tags: statistics

I have a math equation that has II in it I cannot understand what the II function is and what it does. I really appreciate it if you can explain what it is.

[image: equation]

Comment: Probably another notation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket

Comment: As a typographical symbol, it isn't II, but rather it's a capital "I" in the so-called blackboard bold font: $\mathbb I$. Latex font mathbb or, in older versions, Bbb. It's the same you would use for $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a Capital i, as "indicator function"

you can also find $\mathbb{1}$ and indicates that the function is 1 for the values in the braces and zero elsewhere

---

Example,

Suppose you have the following function

$$ y =
\begin{cases}
x,  & \text{if $0<x<1$ } \\
2-x, & \text{if $1\leq x\leq 2$}\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

you can compact the notation and write

$$y=\{1-|1-x|\}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;2]}(x)$$